# Phone call in background of my android app

Tags: android, background, phone-call

I know how to make a phone call from my app using an intent, but the Android dial UI is shown. Is there any possibility of doing it withouth showing the Android dial UI and running the phone call on the background while my app is shown?

Answer (score 1):

First of all make a Service then prepare a flag to check the incoming call is from your own app. 
Now if a call comes, service will find it, if the the flag is true, bring your activity up.

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    //check the flag 
    if(GlobalDefinitions.IsProgramRunning) {
        //open your activity immediately after a call
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, YOURACTIVITY.class);
        intent1.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent1);
        GlobalDefinitions.IsProgramRunning=false;
    }
}
```

For calling:

```
public static void Call( Context context, String phoneNumber) {

    if (!phoneNumber.equals("") ) {
        GlobalDefinitions.IsProgramRunning=true;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the Permission and the Service to your manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".services.OutgoingCallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can request permission `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)

Which allows you to display screens with an "always-on-top" behavior which will be shown over the in-call screen.

`Facebook` uses this permission for their chat heads feature.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, he doesnt want his app to "float" in front of the dialer, he doesnt want the dialer to come up at all.

Comment: I don't know of a way of making a call without ever showing the dialer UI, so I suggest a possible solution of making a screen which will hide the dialer UI behind it.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is absolutely not possible, and for good reason. You should never been placing phone calls without the users knowledge.

Comment: That isn't always the case. In an emergency system, you may want to hide that you are making a call so the intruder doesn't become violent when they notice a phone call being made. I acknowledge what you are saying, but don't think you've thought your answer through as much as you could.